# Excel Macro required to insert a statement after every line

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose i have a set of statements like below in each row in one excel sheet

```
insert into table where column=[test1]
insert into table where column=[test2]
insert into table where column=[test3]
```

Need a macro program to insert "go" under each statement like below

```
insert into table where column=[test1]
go
insert into table where column=[test2]
go
insert into table where column=[test3]
go
```

this is just a sample. I need to do it for more than 200 statements or so.. and i do not want to use the replace option as the end of the statements might change if i use different set of statements.

Comment: Why macro? It isn't hard to insert rows and write "go" in couple of steps.

Comment: Just use control-H, replace "]\n" with "\ngo\n"

Comment: this is just a sample. I need to do it for more than 200 statements or so.. and i cannot use the replace option every time. I also needed a Macro program to learn how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your `statements` are in column A starting in row 1 i.e. `A1`. The following code will insert `Go` after each statement:

```
Sub InsertGo()
    Dim statements(), i As Long
    statements = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    For i = 1 To UBound(statements)
        Range("A" & (i * 2 - 1)) = statements(i, 1)
        Range("A" & (i * 2 - 1)).Offset(1, 0) = "Go"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @alex, It worked perfect. I have certain questions as i am very new to the syntax that u have used.. when i used ?statements in immediate window it returned "type mismatch" error. I assumed it will return the last row of the column. But when i used Range("A7").Value = statements, It copied the first line and printed it in A7 cell. Then why did i receive the error in VB editor? And how did ubound(statements) return the no of rows?
One more final ques - Was statement () necessary ? why was it used like a function. I removed the braces and it worked fine.

Comment: The use of `()` after `statements` declares it as an array. Then when I do `statements = ...` I am reading the range in as an `array`. It is much more efficient. `Ubound` then just gets the length of the array. If the solution worked can you accepts the answer by clicking the tick mark...

Comment: +1. Note, however that you can just declare `statements` as a `Variant`, i.e., `Dim statements`, although I'd include the type to be explicit: `Dim statements as Variant`. A variant can hold an array such as a `Range`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa188497%28v=office.10%29.aspx